# Create bar chart in PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, bar-chart

I am trying to create a bar chart in PHPExcel following the [33-chartcreate-composite-chart.php](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/33chartcreate-bar.php) example.

The code before calling `createExcelGraph()` creates the worksheet shown at the screenshot. The produced chart is added to the worksheet but the resulting file contains no graph or better no graph is shown. No errors are reported by Excel during file load.

[image]

```
private function createExcelStats($occurrences, $labels, $ticks, $graphLabel) {
  require_once __SITE_PATH . 'libraries\Excel\PHPExcel.php';

  $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
  $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("eOccurrence"); 
  $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, "Excel2007");

  $objSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
  $objSheet->setTitle($graphLabel);

  /* writing x-axis */
  for ($i=1;$i<=count($ticks);$i++) {
    $objSheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($i, 1, $ticks[$i-1]);
  }
  /* writing y-axis */
  for ($i=1;$i<=count($labels);$i++) {
    $objSheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $i+1, $labels[$i-1]['label']);
  }

  /* writing content */
  for ($i=0;$i<count($labels);$i++){
    for ($j=0;$j<count($ticks);$j++){
      $objSheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($j+1, $i+2, $occurrences[$i][$j]);
    }    
  }

  $ch = $this->createExcelGraph(count($ticks), count($labels));
  $objSheet->addChart($ch);  

  $this->checkdir(__SITE_PATH . 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'tmp' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
  removeoldfiles(__SITE_PATH . 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'tmp' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 'xlsx');
  $filename =  $graphLabel . '.xlsx';

  $objWriter->save(__SITE_PATH . 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'tmp' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .  $filename);
  return ['code' => '0', 'filename' => $filename];
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

private function createExcelGraph($cols, $rows) {
/* Κάνουμε την υπόθεση ότι το πάνω αριστερό κελί του πίνακα βρίσκεται στο B2 */  

//  Set the Labels for each data series we want to plot
//      Datatype
//      Cell reference for data
//      Format Code
//      Number of datapoints in series
//      Data values
//      Data Marker
  $dataSeriesLabels = array();
  for ($i=1;$i<=$rows;$i++) {    
    $dataSeriesLabels[] = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$A$' . ($i+1), NULL, 1);
  }
//  Set the X-Axis Labels
//      Datatype
//      Cell reference for data
//      Format Code
//      Number of datapoints in series
//      Data values
//      Data Marker
  $col = $this->columnLetter($cols+1);
  $xAxisTickValues = array(    
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$B$1:$' . $col . '$1', NULL, $cols)
  );
//  Set the Data values for each data series we want to plot
//      Datatype
//      Cell reference for data
//      Format Code
//      Number of datapoints in series
//      Data values
//      Data Marker
  $dataSeriesValues = array();
//  for ($i=1;$i<=$rows;$i++) {    
//    $dataSeriesValues[] = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$B$'. ($i+1) . ':$' . $col .'$' . ($i+1), NULL, $cols);
//  }
  for ($i=1;$i<=$cols;$i++) {
    $col = $this->columnLetter($i+1);
    $dataSeriesValues[] = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$' . $col . '$2:$' . $col . '$' . ($rows+1), NULL, $rows);
  }        
//  Build the dataseries
$series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART,       // plotType
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_CLUSTERED,  // plotGrouping
    range(0, count($dataSeriesValues)-1),           // plotOrder
    $dataSeriesLabels,                              // plotLabel
    $xAxisTickValues,                               // plotCategory
    $dataSeriesValues                               // plotValues
);
//  Set additional dataseries parameters
//      Make it a horizontal bar rather than a vertical column graph
$series->setPlotDirection(PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_BAR);

//  Set the series in the plot area
$plotArea = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea(NULL, array($series));
//  Set the chart legend
$legend = new PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, NULL, false);

$title = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Test Bar Chart');
$yAxisLabel = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Value ($k)');


//  Create the chart
$chart = new PHPExcel_Chart(
    'chart1',       // name
    $title,         // title
    $legend,        // legend
    $plotArea,      // plotArea
    true,           // plotVisibleOnly
    0,              // displayBlanksAs
    NULL,           // xAxisLabel
    $yAxisLabel     // yAxisLabel
);

//  Set the position where the chart should appear in the worksheet
$chart->setTopLeftPosition('A7');
$chart->setBottomRightPosition('H5');

//  Add the chart to the worksheet
//$objWorksheet->addChart($chart);  
return $chart;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell the Writer to include charts when writing the spreadsheet file:

```
$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
```

Comment: Now I'm getting an error from Excel while opening the created file     `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><logFileName>error089760_02.xml</logFileName><summary>Errors were detected in file 'C:\Temp\Monthly graph for year 2016 (1).xlsx'</summary><removedParts summary="Following is a list of removed parts:"><removedPart>Removed Part: /xl/drawings/drawing1.xml part.  (Drawing shape)</removedPart></removedParts></recoveryLog>`